# Is “symmetricity” a word?

Tags: meaning, is-it-a-word, derivational-morphology

Some online resources that have a meaning for this word

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/symmetricity

https://www.wordnik.com/words/symmetricity

But I am not sure whether they are correct. Can anyone clear my doubt on this?

Comment: Welcome to ELU. This site strives to provide well researched, intriguing questions. Take the [site tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) or have a look at the [help center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help) to find out more about good questions.

Comment: Your second source cites the first and that is publicly editable... No actual dictionary lists the word: http://www.onelook.com/?w=symmetricity&ls=a

Comment: @Helmar But some reputable journals do publish articles that have this word in its title. Yes, so do I consider this as a word or its not a word.

Comment: That information is dubiously absent from your question...

Comment: It may appear in the jargon of certain scholarly disciplines, but it's not present in most general dictionaries.  This is probably because its supposed meaning, "the condition of being symmetric", is already adequately expressed in the word "symmetry".

Comment: What is it that you mean when you ask whether you should "consider this a word"? You've even yourself found this word; how could it possibly ***not*** be a word?

Comment: symmetricality of something is OK.

Comment: @DougWarren If it is a not a dictionary word, I can at least avoid using it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Tiger, Tiger: *Symmetricity, Symmetricality,* or *Symmetricalness*?

It doesn't really matter whether this or that dictionary includes or omits it. It is the regular product of applying productive derivational morphology to a basic English word for conversion purposes.

It doesn’t matter whether you use *symmetricity, symmetricality,* or *symmetricalness* — any native speaker and indeed any competent second-language user will know exactly what you mean by your term.

This is because you’ve used a basic vocabulary term, the adjective *symmetric*, and applyied standard suffixes to convert that adjective into a substantive.

### The Mathematics of Nominalization Doubly Applied

However, careful writers will wonder why you used a noun-making suffix on an adjective which was itself ***already*** the product of someone else applying an adjective-making suffix to. In other words, this math is overly complicated:

```
adjective₁ = noun₁      + adjective-making suffix
noun₂      = adjective₁ + noun-making      suffix
noun₂      = noun₁      + adjective-making suffix + noun-making suffix
```

Seems to me you should use *noun*<sub>1</sub> in the first place instead of adding two suffixes to it to make *noun*<sub>2</sub>.

What’s the original noun, you ask? That would be ***symmetry***.

---

<sub>*Tiger, tiger, burning bright
In the forests of the night,
What immortal hand or eye
Dare frame thy fearful symmetry?*</sub>

Comment: the fact is that symmetricity is used with a specific connotation, not just as a synonym of symmetry, that's why "new" nouns are ofen used in technology or science for instance.

Comment: @RaajaG You may also wish to also vote for tchrist's answer if you agree with it. I disagree with it though, so I will be voting against it. I hope to make an answer of my own explaining exactly why if the question is ever reopened. Summarized into what's appropriate for an answer's comment, I presently disagree with the assertion that any competent speaker of the language would recognize the signification of this particular suffix combination due to the semantic significations of the suffixes which I think tchrist neglected to analyze. I'll explain it further if the question's ever reopened.

Comment: @Tonepoet Though I would like to upvote tchrist answer, I could not do so because of my low reputation.